# how to access nth element of array in a expect script where n is a command line arg

Tags: tcl, expect

I am trying to automate vpn login using expect script. I intend to choose a vpn address from a list of addresses as same address doesn't work all the time.
I have this right now:

`cat connect_script`

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

# example-vpn1.com
# example-vpn2.com
# example-vpn3.com

spawn /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect example-vpn1.com

expect {
    "Username:*" {
        sleep 1
        send "username\r"
        exp_continue
    } 
    "Password:" {
        sleep 1
        send "password\r"
        exp_continue
    } 
}
```

This works fine but often `example-vpn1.com` will stop working, so i will manually change `example-vpn1.com` to `example-vpn2.com`

I want to create an array like

`vpnaddr = [example-vpn1.com, example-vpn2.com, example-vpn3.com]`

and then send a command-line argument

e.g. `connect_script 0` or `connect_script 1`

such that `vaddr[0]` or `vaddr[1]` is used to connect to vpn in expect script.

Something like below code.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set vpnaddr [list example-vpn1.com example-vpn2.com example-vpn3.com]

set IDX [lindex $argv 0]

spawn /opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpn connect vpnaddr[IDX]

expect {
    "Username:*" {
        sleep 1
        send "username\r"
        exp_continue
    } 
    "Password:" {
        sleep 1
        send "password\r"
        exp_continue
    } 
}
```

what is the correct way to do `vpnaddr[IDX]` here?

Comment: you're already using `lindex` on `argv`. that's just the correct way. to write a loop you can use [for](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/for.html) or [foreach](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.html).

Comment: i dont want to write a loop. i want to access array by index. Is that doable in expect?
If not, what is the alternative.

Comment: I bet that this question got downvotes because you are asking how to get an item from a Tcl list, which is something you'd learn quickly when learning the basics of Tcl.    (https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl14.html)   In your example, you already used `lindex` once to get the first item in `$argv` but you still didn't know how to get an item from the `$vpnaddr` list.

Comment: I'm sorry you're frustrated. The reaction you're getting is not "egositic" or "narcissistic", it's more like confusion: your answer is right there in your code, you're already using it for A, how are you missing it for B? It is a well written question, but I'd be hard pressed to agree with researched.

Comment: @glennjackman thank you too for making me see the problem in my question. I will be more mindful next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are calling an array is a Tcl list.   Using correct terms is important because a Tcl array is something different.

Use the `lindex` command to get an item from a list, not square brackets.
Instead of `vpnaddr[IDX]`, you need to do `[lindex $vpnaddr $IDX]`.